# Обмен данных в реальном времени

Tags: асинхронность, php

Собственно вопрос в том, с помощью чего реализовать обмен данных между веб-сервером и браузером в реальном времени. Знаю только о WebSocket'ах.

Идея заключается в создании игры, в которой необходимо будет обмениваться данными в реальном времени между пользователями в одной группе.

Какие еще есть инструменты? Заранее огромное спасибо.

Comment: асинхронное программирование на пхп это боль и пытка, есть несколько реализаций типа http://reactphp.org/ и http://daemon.io/ но я вам сразу скажу, что вы быстрее выучите ноду с экспрессом, чем на них что нить стоящее напишите.

Comment: возможно тогда посоветуете на чем это лучше всего реализуется? за ссылки огромное спасибо.

Comment: да на чем угодно, хоть на C++ - лишь бы http библиотеки серверные реализующие HTTP 1.1 были :) (если на php, то забудьте про  $_POST[] - форму(включая разбор mime-type ) будете сами парсить на сервере да и ответ формировать тоже вручную) скорее  всего вам будет проще всего это реализовать на node + express, т.к. js вы  уже наверное знаете.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. С JS конечно же я знаком и довольно неплохо, посмотрю в сторону node + express :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чем вебсокеты не подходят? Нормальная реализация есть например в [phpDaemon](http://habrahabr.ru/post/79377/)

В старый браузерах используют Flash обертки

Если все плохо, и дело происходит на хостинге, есть [long polling](http://habrahabr.ru/post/128535/), но 
это вот и правда боль и страдания

В сторону node я бы смотрел в последнюю очередь, но это мое личное мнение

Comment: По поводу последней строчки, почему Вы так думаете? Интересно полное мнение.

Comment: @manticore мож человек на личном опыте не совладал с данным зверьком.